# How to add to each query new value and key JSON MySQL read

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have one PHP script that reads from database and then generates JSON format string so that i can read on android device and show my covers and informations. The problem is how to add to each MySQL return index at end key name [SOURCE] = 'MYSOURCE4'?

Here is code that i im using:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qmovies)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
            $id = $row['id'];

            switch(true) {
            case $id > 4428:
                $src = 'disk3.wuk';
                break;
            case $id > 2216:
                $src = 'disk2.wuk';
                break;
            default:
                $src = 'disk1.wuk';
                break;
            }
        }

        array_push($rows['0'], $src);
        print json_encode($rows);
```

So i get this:

[{"id":"4457","title":"hahahah","source":"disk3.wuk"},{"id":"2000","title":"uuuuuu"}]

I need to get this:

[{"id":"4457","title":"hahahah","source":"disk3.wuk"},{"id":"2000","title":"uuuuuu","source":"disk2.wuk"}]

So how to add at end of MySQL read in while loop at each read end id array key and value source?

Thanks.

Comment: before close bracket write ` $rows[count($rows)-1]['source'] = $src;`

Comment: Can you post the query? Also, are diskX.wuk sequential like disk1.wuk, disk2.wuk, disk3.wuk, disk4.wuk etc ?

Comment: thanks...now it works..i just added solution from splash58 and it works...thanks again:)